# oracle SUBSTR to postgres SUBSTR function

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

I have a function in oracle that i need converted to postgres.

i can't seem to find a reason for this difference in docs docs but:

oracle:

```
SELECT substr('1236',-4, 4) FROM DUAL;
    Result: 1236
```

postgres:

```
SELECT substr('1236',-4, 4);
    Result: empty (Null)
```

i need an output similiar to oracle and i cant seem to understand why the postgres function differs, and what i can use as an alternative

Comment: `substr()` doesn't accept a negative starting position in Postgres

Comment: hmmm, any idea for the nearest alternative?

Comment: It does accept, but shows different beheavior, `select substr('string', -1, 3)` returns st. I think it assumes you have something in -ve positions, and takes in account but returns only the valid values, so above returns `select substr('string', 1, 1)`

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little confused by your confusion.  Oracle is quite clear that a negative position counts back from the end of the string.

*Nothing* in the Postgres documentation suggests that this behavior.  There is no mention of negative positions (as far as I can tell) for any string functions other than `left()` and `right()`.  And no hint whatsoever that negative positions have a special meaning in other contexts.

Postgres fortunately has a simpler way to do what you want:

```
select right('1236', 4)
```